# Doubt using RegionCentroid

Tags: regions, education

TuI know an equation that gives me the barycenter of a circle:

[image]

```
r = 5;
H = r;
y = (3 (2 r - H)^2)/(4 (3 r - H)) // N
```

> $1.875$

Using RegionCentroid on a solid I got the same result as above

```
cutBall[r_, h_] := 
 RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r], HalfSpace[{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -h}]]

RegionCentroid[cutBall[5, 0]][[3]] // N

BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[cutBall[5, 0], ViewPoint -> Front]
```

> $1.875$

[image]

In another question, I asked about centroid of an area described by a function. I tried to use what I learned, but the outputs are not the same. Where is the error?

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 && y >= 0, {x, y}];

RegionCentroid[region][[2]] // N

RegionPlot[region, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@RegionCentroid[region]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}]
```

> $2.12207$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your formula is correct?

Comment: So, you're formula is for 3 dimensions, and you expect it to work in 2 dimensions as well?

Comment: @CarlWoll It must be a very subtle mistake that I have not seen yet

Comment: The centroid of a 3d object is not the same as the centroid of a similar 2d object. The equivalent `ImplicitRegion` formulation is `ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2+z^2<r^2 && y>0, {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: @Carl Will That is, the equation I have is only acceptable for spheres.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Carl Woll proved:

For future doubts that may occur.

The error in the question as we can see is not relative to Mathematica, but mathematical concept error.

The equation below is valid only to describe the barycentre of a solid of revolution.

$\frac{3 (2 r-H)^2}{4 (3 r-H)}$

By @Carl Woll

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 5^2 && y > 0, {x, y, z}]

RegionCentroid[region][[2]] // N
```

> $1.875$